# How to delete an aws cloudfront Origin Access Identity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

In the AWS Console > CloudFront Distributions,

I click on my Distribution ID, and I go to the Origins tab, and I edit the origin.

I set the Restrict Bucket Access to Yes.

Here, I can create a new identity, or select an existing identity.

So, the question is, how can I delete an existing identity?

Answer (score 13):

Deleting identities is done from the main CloudFront interface rather than the distribution level.

Go to the [CloudFront console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/home), click the 'Origin Access Identity' link in the left hand nav, and provided it is not currently associated with any distributions, you'll be able to delete it from there.